# Select Box looks different in Opera?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, opera

the following is my desired result. It works fine in Chrome, IE and FF:

[image: Perfect]

this is my result when I am using Opera:

[image: broken]

Demo site: http://www.unforgivengamers.com

Help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix the difference by assiginig height to the input.

See this example, there is no difference in height in  any browser:

http://jsbin.com/ijuzas/1/edit

If you assign the same height to the select and input element it should be equal.

Using operas inspect element i changed the height to 14px and it looked the same.

```
#menu form input[type="text"] {
height:14px;
}
```

However, it would be best to set the same height on both select and input and not leave it unset.

Comment: It is still misaligned on my end: http://gyazo.com/7f0902d6b2b09ff6b7093b0922b5f344.png?1357389528 Check your jsbin project with opera.

Comment: misaligned yes, but the height is equal. add float left see http://jsbin.com/ijuzas/3/edit

Comment: Okay, so how would I go about doing this without a float left?

Comment: dont see a way around it. just use float left. alternatively you could use absolute positioning, but then you also need position relative on the parent.

Comment: try this: box-sizing: border-box;

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using an ugly css hack to only target opera with a slightly different padding for the select.

```
x:-o-prefocus, #menu select {
 padding: 5px 2px 5px 0;
}
```